# Trying to learn JAVA and I want to write 99 bottles of beer song

Tags: java

I am very new to JAVA programming and have only programmed in Python before. 
I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting a duplicate line of " # of bottles of beer on the wall" when I execute my code.

```
    package BeerBottle;

    public class BeerBot {
  public static void main (String [] args){
      int beerNum = 99;
      String word = "bottles";

      while (beerNum > 0) {

      if (beerNum == 1) {
      word = "bottle";
      } else {
      word = "bottles";
      }
    System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " " + "of beer on the wall");
    System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " " + "of beer");
    System.out.println("Take one down");
    System.out.println("pass it around");
    beerNum = beerNum -1;

    if (beerNum > 0) {
        System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " " + "of beer on the wall"); // I think it might be this line but I need it 
    } else {
        System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
    }
    }
   }
```

}

The result I get is this:

```
    2 bottles of beer on the wall
    2 bottles of beer on the wall (duplicate)
    2 bottles of beer
    Take one down
    pass it around
    1 bottles of beer on the wall
    1 bottle of beer on the wall (duplicate)
    1 bottle of beer
    Take one down
    pass it around
    No more bottles of beer on the wall
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last printed line of the loop is identical to the first printed line of the next loop, so it's not a problem.  To visually separate each loop's output, print a blank line at the very end of the method.  Then you'll see something like this:

```
2 bottles of beer on the wall  // Last line of a loop

2 bottles of beer on the wall  // First line of the next loop
2 bottles of beer
Take one down
pass it around
1 bottles of beer on the wall  // Last line of a loop

1 bottle of beer on the wall   // First line of next loop
1 bottle of beer
Take one down
pass it around
No more bottles of beer on the wall
```

Comment: You'll want to move the `if` block that decides "bottle" vs. "bottles"  to immediately after you subtract one from `beerNum` to avoid `1 bottles of beer on the wall` (plural "bottles" on 1).

Comment: It's better to get this case out of the loop, because if it doesn't do exactly the same, why are we treating like if it does?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're actually getting a unintended duplicate line and not mistaking the last line of one stanza with the first of the next?  Try adding an extra empty line at the end of each stanza to clearly see the difference.

This can be done with an extra System.out.println("") or adding a "\n" to the end of the previous one.

Also, you will want to reevaluate what beer-word you are using as soon as you decrement the number of beers.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `for` loop instead a `while`. I could get out of the loop the 2 last iterations, that must deal with the "bottle/bottles" stuff.

My loop will look like that:

```
for (int num_beers=99; i>2; i--) {
  String output = num_bers + " bottles of beer";

  System.out.println(output + " on the wall");
  System.out.println(output);
  System.out.println("Take one down\npass it around");
  System.out.println(output.replace(num_beers, num_beers-1) + " on the wall");
}
```

With that loop, the last string printed will be "2 bottles of beer on the wall" (first time).

Only for practice, it will be nice to make the same example but using a recursive method